# How can you determine if a radio button was set checked=true by 3rd party JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Setting a radio button to `checked=true` programatically doesn't fire a change event. How can I know if a radio button was checked by a script?

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wykEx/7/

In Firebug, no change events are logged to the console unless you manually click on the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to set up a timer and poll for changes. Of course it may not be the most elegant solution but it should be good enough and should work in all browsers.

The biggest caveat with doing it this way is that you may loose some transitions if code changes the checked attribute of your input element too often.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var elem = $('twoRadioBtn');
    if(elem.checked != elem.lastchecked)
    {
        console.log('TWO changed!');

        elem.lastchecked = elem.checked;
    }
}, 100);        // poll every 100 ms.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Miky. I'd obviously like to avoid polling if I can. I'm hoping someone will have another solution. I even tried using object.watch but it seems, in Firefox at least, that the watch event is not triggered when the checked property changes.

Comment: I don't know if you'll be able to find a consistent solution to work in all browsers - if there is even a way.. Good luck!